# How to make random.randint() more random

Tags: python

So I am writing my first program and it started as a just a something that rolls random dice values but I expanded it to and its a lot more fun.The problem I am having is that sometimes this function

```
def mathproblem(stuff): 

    if stuff == '1': 
        probuno=int(raw_input("can you solve: sqrt(169)+4")) 
        if probuno==17: 
            print('correct you may proceed') 
            rollify=True 
        else: 
            rollify=False 
    elif stuff=='2': 
        probdos=int(raw_input("can you solve: 47.9+36-14.8")) 
        if probdos==69.1: 
            print('YEEEET') 
            rollify=True 
        else: 
            print('you filthy wanker') 
            rollify=False 
    elif stuff == '3': 
        probtres=int(raw_input("can you solve: 32^2 -sqrt(625)")) 
        if probtres==399: 
            print('WOOOO') 
            rollify=True 
        else: 
            print('Wow... that was awful') 
            rollify=False 
    elif stuff=='4': 
        probquatro=int(raw_input("can you solve: ln(1)-e^0")) 
        if probquatro==-1: 
            print('MISSION ACCOMPLISHED') 
            rollify=True 
        else: 
            print('your parents probably hate you') 
            rollify=False 

    elif stuff=='5': 
        probcinco=(raw_input("can you solve: sqrt(-1)")) 
        if probcinco=='i': 
            print('wow you must be a genius') 
            rollify=True 
        else: 
            print('L') 
            rollify=False
```

which gets used here

```
elif guess>rand: 
   print('HALT! YOU MAY PROCEED ONLY IF YOU...') 

    mathproblem(oof)
```

and `oof=random.randint(min,max)` 
so every few times It sends the same problem over and over again, is there any way I can make this more random?
edit: sorry for the teenager edginess ;)

Comment: Ironically, fixing that would make it less random. Random sequences sometimes contain consecutive elements. Are you actually concerned about how random it is, or do you just want to prevent the same result twice (which again will make it less random)?

Comment: aaah but `rand` doesn't change: you have to update it between tests...

Comment: You only have 5 questions. Create a list of numbers 1-5, randomized. [How do I create a list of numbers without duplicates?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9755538)

Comment: `oof` gets its value when you execute `oof=random.randint(min,max)`. Use `mathproblem(random.randint(min,max))` to get a new random value on each call

Comment: `random.randint` returns an int, and you're comparing it with strings?

Comment: ooh okay thank you

Comment: i guess I should fix that

Answer (score 1):

"More random" is definitely not what you're asking for.

But I believe that the behaviour you want is something like:

```
def not_really_random(r_min, r_max):
    seq = range(r_min, r_max+1)
    while True:
        random.shuffle(seq)
        for n in seq:
            yield n


for oof in not_really_random(a, b):
    mathproblem(oof)
```

Which will basically cycle through all the different problems in random orders (with a slight chance that after going through all the problems, it's start again at the last problem you saw)